# Typescript: cannot find module '@env' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, geolocalización, .env

Estoy usando la libreria react-native-maps para utilizar la geolocalización en mi proyecto de rn con javascript, pero estoy recibiendo este error "cannot find module '@env' or its corresponding type declarations" al tratar de importar la api key desde su archivo env, al componente que hace render del mapa, estos son mis archivos (he tratado con yarn add react-native-dotenv pero no me funciona(?)):

update: encontré algo que funcionó, lo dejo hasta abajo

archivo env:

```
GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY=key..
```

mi archivo babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true)
    return {
        presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
        plugins: [
            [
                'module:react-native-dotenv',
                {
                    moduleName: '@env',
                    path: '.env',
                    blacklist: null,
                    whitelist: null,
                    safe: false,
                    allowUndefined: true
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

mis dependencias:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.4.8",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.20",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "dripsy": "^3.2.1",
    "expo": "~43.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.13.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.13",
    "expo-web-browser": "^10.1.0",
    "graphql": "15.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.19.5",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-anchor-carousel": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.14.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.6",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-incode-sdk": "https://sdk-js.s3.amazonaws.com/react-native/react-native-incode-sdk-5.1.0-nvc.tgz",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.28.1",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.4.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.13.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.17.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0"
  },
```

Estas son las importaciones que estoy usando en el componente donde quiero importar la llave de .env

```
import * as React from 'react'
import MapView, { Marker, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps'
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions'
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY } from '@env'
```

y este es el error en la importación de '@env'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté con npm install --save @types/react-native-dotenv pero me tira los errores que muestro debajo

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @expo/html-elements@0.0.1
npm WARN Found: react-native-web@0.17.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-native-web
npm WARN   peer react-native-web@">= 0.11" from react-native-maps@0.28.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-maps
npm WARN     react-native-maps@"0.28.1" from the root project
npm WARN   1 more (the root project)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-native-web@"~0.13.7" from @expo/html-elements@0.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/@expo/html-elements
npm WARN   @expo/html-elements@"^0.0.1" from @dripsy/core@3.6.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@dripsy/core
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-web@0.13.18
npm WARN node_modules/react-native-web
npm WARN   peer react-native-web@"~0.13.7" from @expo/html-elements@0.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@expo/html-elements
npm WARN     @expo/html-elements@"^0.0.1" from @dripsy/core@3.6.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@dripsy/core
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-maps-directions@1.9.0npm ERR! Found: react-native-maps@0.28.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-maps
npm ERR!   react-native-maps@"0.28.1" from the root project 
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-maps@">=1.0.0" from react-native-maps-directions@1.9.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-maps-directions
npm ERR!   react-native-maps-directions@"^1.9.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-maps@1.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-maps
npm ERR!   peer react-native-maps@">=1.0.0" from react-native-maps-directions@1.9.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-maps-directions        
npm ERR!     react-native-maps-directions@"^1.9.0" from the 
root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry     
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps   
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Andoni\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:        
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andoni\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-21T17_01_10_623Z-debug-0.log
```

RESPUESTA:
hice un archivo tsx con la clave como const a exportar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo importé de esta manera en mi archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que falta un type declaration de TS puede que haya que instalar un type declaration para `react-native-dotenv`

Comment: probé con yarn add react-native-dotenv como se usa en la documentación, pero no me funciona

Comment: ese es el paquete, lo que necesitas son los type definitions de TypeScript, prueba con [este](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-native-dotenv) avisanos si logras avanzar

Comment: me tira varios errores en las dependencias al tratar de instalarlo, arriba te muestro

Comment: en el proyecto estamos usando yarn, no se si tenga que ver

Comment: intenta con `yarn install @types/react-native-dotenv` haber que dice

Comment: nada todavia, también probé con yarn add @types/react-native-dotenv y tampoco

Comment: agregué la llave a un archivo tsx y lo importé al que necesitaba, así funcionó

Comment: que bien, puedes publicar tu respuesta, tengo curiosidad, se supone que las llaves van en un archivo .env, pense que ya tenias eso configurado, saludos

Comment: si lo estuve intentando con .env, pero al final me funcionó como lo actualicé al final de la pregunta, un archivo tsx con la clave como export const, luego lo importé al archivo donde quería usarlo